# cannot resolve custom object graphql schema

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to set up my schema for Apollo Server, and I'm running into an error. I'm not really sure how to put this question so I will post text/code than necessary.

"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.id."

My resolvers/index.js look like this:

```js
import * as Mutation from "./Mutation";
import * as Query from "./Query";
import User from "./User";

const resolvers = { Mutation, Query, User };

console.log(resolvers);
export default resolvers;
```

Which produces the following output:

```html
{
Mutation: {
  createListing: [Getter],
  updateListing: [Getter],
  deleteListing: [Getter],
  createUser: [Getter]
},

Query: { listings: [Getter], listing: [Getter], userLogin: [Getter] },

User: [AsyncFunction: user]
}
```

My typeDefs file looks like this

```js
import { gql } from "apollo-server";

const typeDefs = gql`
 type Listing {
  description: String!
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  createdBy: User!
 }

 type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
 }

 type AuthData {
  id: ID!
  token: String!
  expiresIn: String!
 }

 input UserInput {
  email: String!
  password: String!
 }

 input ListingInput {
  id: ID
  title: String!
  description: String!
 }

 type Mutation {
  createUser(userInput: UserInput): User!
  createListing(listingInput: ListingInput): Listing!
  updateListing(listingInput: ListingInput): Listing!
  deleteListing(id: ID!): Boolean!
 }

 type Query {
  listings: [Listing!]!
  listing(id: ID!): Listing!
  userLogin(userInput: UserInput): AuthData!
 }
`;

export default typeDefs;
```

The problem is I don't know how get User data on the Listing Type

createdBy is actually ID! field and I'd like graphQL to get User data for me. Below is the query I've been trying to use.

```js
query {
listing(id: 35) 
{
    id
 title
 createdBy {
        id
        email
    }
}
}
```

Graphql beginner here. Am I using the right approach?
I can also provide the git repo, if needed. How do I reorganize this so it works?

Comment: `listing(id)` resolver ? doesn't return user type for `createdBy` - probably returns only user `id` from DB listing record .. use join

Answer (score 0):

Graphql will throw this error if your resolver returns null for a required property.

it looks like you've only defined resolvers for `Mutation`, `Query` and `User`, but you'll want to make another one for listing that can be used to resolve the createdBy field. I'd imagine it'd look something like this:

`Listing.js`

```
const Listing = {
  createdBy: (root, args, ctx) => {
    //code to fetch actual user goes here, you'd presumably have some kind of
    //id on the listing like 'creator' that refers to a user id which you could
    //access from the root like root.creator
    return {
      id: '1',
      email: 'foo@bar.com'
    }
  }
}

export default Listing
```